# Get count of categories based on condition of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like,

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.DataFrame({'Age1': [45, 48, 52, 51, 48, 45, 62, 47, 65, 50], 'Age2': [37, 68, 71, 54, 67, 59, 95, 56, 41, 42]})
```

I need to get the count of categorise (<40, 40-50, 50-60, >60) by comparing two columns together.

```
count1=[len(data[(data['Age1']<40) & (data['Age2'] < 40)]), len(data[(data['Age1']>=40) & (data['Age1']<50) &(data['Age2'] < 40)]),len(data[(data['Age1']>=50) & (data['Age1']<60) &(data['Age2'] < 40)]),len(data[(data['Age1']>=60) &(data['Age2'] < 40)])]
count2=[len(data[(data['Age1']<40) & (data['Age2']>= 40) & (data['Age2']< 50)]), len(data[(data['Age1']>=40) & (data['Age1']<50) & (data['Age2']>= 40) & (data['Age2']< 50)]),len(data[(data['Age1']>=50) & (data['Age1']<60) & (data['Age2']>= 40) & (data['Age2']< 50)]), len(data[(data['Age1']>60) & (data['Age2']>= 40) & (data['Age2']< 50)])]
count3=[len(data[(data['Age1']<40) & (data['Age2']>= 50) & (data['Age2']< 60)]), len(data[(data['Age1']>=40) & (data['Age1']<50) & (data['Age2']>= 50) & (data['Age2']< 60)]),len(data[(data['Age1']>=50) & (data['Age1']<60) & (data['Age2']>= 50) & (data['Age2']< 60)]), len(data[(data['Age1']>60) & (data['Age2']>= 50) & (data['Age2']< 60)])]
count4=[len(data[(data['Age1']<40) & (data['Age2']> 60)]), len(data[(data['Age1']>=40) & (data['Age1']<50) & (data['Age2']> 60)]) ,len(data[(data['Age1']>=50) & (data['Age1']<60) & (data['Age2']> 60)]), len(data[(data['Age1']>60) & (data['Age2']> 60)])]
count=[count1,count2,count3,count4]

[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1, 1]]
```

Is there any way to simplify this code in few lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.cut` to binarize the columns, then `pd.crosstab`:

```
bins = [-np.inf, 40, 50, 60, np.inf]
pd.crosstab(pd.cut(data['Age1'],bins=bins), pd.cut(data['Age2'],bins=bins))
```

Output:

```
Age2          (-inf, 40.0]  (40.0, 50.0]  (50.0, 60.0]  (60.0, inf]
Age1                                                               
(40.0, 50.0]             1             1             2            2
(50.0, 60.0]             0             0             1            1
(60.0, inf]              0             1             0            1
```

Comment: use `dropna = False` as OP needs all levels to be present

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define the bins and labels(optional) to categorize your column, and then store them into new columns.

```
# Define the age bins
bins = [-np.inf, 40, 50, 60, np.inf]

# Define the age labels
labels = ['<40', '40-50', '50-60', '>60']

# Add a new column to the dataframe with the age categories
# Categorize the ages in both columns
df['Age 1 Category'] = pd.cut(df['Age1'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
df['Age 2 Category'] = pd.cut(df['Age2'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Now you can use [`crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) function that calculates the frequency table of the factors.

```
# Create a cross-tabulation of the two columns
result = pd.crosstab(df['Age 1 Category'], df['Age 2 Category'])

# Print the resulting matrix
print(result)
```

The output will be :

```
Age 2 Category  <40  40-50  50-60  >60
Age 1 Category                        
40-50             1      1      2    2
50-60             0      0      1    1
>60               0      1      0    1
```